# Throttling outgoing HTTP requests with Async Jersey HTTP Client using RxJava

Tags: http, jersey, rx-java, vert.x, throttling

I am trying to throttle outgoing http requests using Jersey Client. Since I am running is a Vertx Verticle I created a special RateLimiter class to handle throttling.

My goal is to prevent HTTP calls from being made at a greater rate than 1 per second. the idea is that a submitted callable will run using the single threaded ExecutorService so that I can block that single thread in order to guarantee that these tasks are not handled in a greater rate.

Basically the only public method in this class is "call" :

```
 public <T> Observable<T> call(Callable<Observable<T>> action) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {

        Observable<Observable<T>> observed =
                Observable.from(executor.submit(() -> {                         
                        return action.call();
                    })
                ).doOnError(throwable -> {
                               logger.error(throwable);
                           }
                );

        observed.subscribe(t -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                t.subscribe(data -> {
                    try {
                        subscriber.onNext(data);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        subscriber.onError(e);
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

this is my current implementation which uses 1 second sleep no matter how much time has passed since the previous call. initially I tried using a ScheduledExecutorService and calculate the delay time so that I will submit requests exactly at the rate of 1 per second. however, in both cases it often fails to meet the rate restrictions and I get two requests submitted immediately one after the other.

My assumption is that somewhere the requests is being handed to a different executing queue which is being polled by a different thread continuously, so that if for some reason that thread was busy and two requests exist in the queue at the same time, they will be executed sequentially but with no delays.

Any Ideas how to resolve this? maybe a different approach?

Comment: What's wrong with [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) operator?

Comment: Will it not filter out events not meeting the within a specified duration? I would like to emit all requests but at the same rate.  The term "emit" in the documentation refers to the callback being called. but I don't see how it guarantees the execution of the outgoing requests in the rate I need it to.

Would be very helpful if you could elaborate with a code sample how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Please let me sum up your question, that I do understand it properly. You have some web-service done with Vertx. The service in question can be called multiple times in one second. The service itself does a rest-call with Jersey Client. The rest-calles should be throttled with 1 per second. Every call to the web-service (Vertx) should be processed with a result. Lets take 5 requests at one second. Then the first will be triggered against rest. The other four will wait one second untill the next one will be processed? For the last request you would wait 5 seconds to response?

Comment: @YanivCohen then check `buffer` with timeout.

Comment: Actually it's a bit simpler than that. let me put it this way: I have a web service working on top of vert.x (AKA My Service), the service is using jersey http client to make http rest calls to a different web service (AKA Other Service) which only allows 1 request per second.  a single rest call to my service will create many requests to the other service. 

As long as the other service is being hit by my service at the rate of 1 request per second I should be ok.

Comment: Ok, I will read up on VertX and try to solve your question.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with simple Vertx event bus and a queue, from which you poll every second:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    vertx.deployVerticle(new DebounceVerticle(), (r) -> {

        // Ok, verticle is ready!
        // Request to send 10 events in 1 second
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            vertx.eventBus().publish("call", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
    });


}


private static class DebounceVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    HttpClient client;
    @Override
    public void start() {
        client = vertx.createHttpClient();

        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("call", (payload) -> {
            String message = (String) payload.body();
            queue.add(message);
            System.out.println(String.format("I got %s but I don't know when it will be executed", message));
        });

        vertx.setPeriodic(1000, (l) -> {
            String message = queue.poll();

            if (message != null) {
                System.out.println(String.format("I'm finally sending %s", message));

                //Do your client magic
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I would use Guava rate limiter only that I have two issues with it:

Answer (score 2):

Just prepend web service call with guava [RateLimiter](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java). Here's an example in RxJava which shows how events every 500ms are throttled to be once per second.

```
    Function<Long, Long> throttlingFunction = new Function<Long, Long>() {
        private RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(1.0);

        public Long apply(Long t) throws Exception {
            limiter.acquire();
            return t;
        }
    };
    Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(throttlingFunction)
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
        public void accept(Long t) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    });
```

Also in vert.x all the blocking stuff is supposed to be run with the help of [executeBlocking](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#executeBlocking-io.vertx.core.Handler-boolean-io.vertx.core.Handler-).